# Cypress test scenario logging in Via Auth0

Tags: function, automation, single-sign-on, auth0, cypress

I've started using Cypress to test our front End Internal Application (being built using Angular5), which uses Auth0 as login authentication.

I'm a QA with **NO** experience of any sort of coding, so I was quite pleased when I managed to get a few tests working (and passing).

However I have hit a stumbling block.  Even though I can use Cypress to test that the Auth0 login works; when the login is successful it is not opening the application in the test as it would if I were manually testing.

Below is my test that runs the Auth0 authentication test.

```
describe('My Login Test', function (){
    it('Visit Risk App Landing Page', function (){
        const typedText = 'user-email-address'
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/workflow')
        cy.get('button').click()
        cy.get('input.auth0-lock-input').first()
        .type(typedText)
        .should('have.value', typedText)
        cy.get('button').click()
        cy.url().should('eq','http://localhost:3000/workflow')
    })
})
```

I'm also trying to create a function where I can call Auth0 and store the response so I don't have to run a login scenario before every tests that runs for the rest of the application, but as I said I have no coding experience and I've found that creating a function is far different to creating a test as that shown above.
If anyone could offer any suggestions/tips/clues, they would all be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

can't help you with your first question. But as for extracting your login code for reusablitity you could create a cypress command https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, password) => {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/workflow')
        cy.get('button').click()
        cy.get('input.auth0-lock-input').first()
        .type(email)
        cy.get('button').click()
        cy.url().should('eq','http://localhost:3000/workflow')
})
```

Then from within your tests you could call it like:

```
cy.login('some-email', 'somepassword')
```